# is there an existing flow control that can do aggregation for the incoming N message(or all the incoming message within a timeout)

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

What I am trying to do is to aggregate the N incoming messages or all the incoming message within a timeout, then it will send to the next step. (an api call).
Because I don't want to hit the api too frequent, so i only want to send aggregate message over.

is there an existing flow control I can use or I have to create custom flow control?

Thank you
Yiwen

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scatter-gather and flow ref for calling multiple flows and aggregate the message .. If you want some feature like timeout .. you can use ALL router (Depreciated) flow reference and collection-aggregator to aggregate the messages